# The file /_controltemplates/15/ does not exist

Tags: web-part

We are planning to migrate from share point 2010 to SharePoint 2013.So we have created one POC environment to test the customizations(master pages,Page layouts,web parts,site definition,Site templates) in SharePoint 2013.We have installed Visual Studio 2012 to convert VS2010 solution.We have done with the converstion from VS2010 solutions to VS2012.

We have followed all the below steps to test the same functionality.

1. Install Visual Studio 2012 and reopen solution in VS 2012
2. Change .NET Framework version to  v4.5
3. Update existing reference of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI". (may need to other dlls reference as well)
4. Add a property ‘SharePointVersion =”15.0"’ in  element in the manifest file. (otherwise it gets installed into SharePoint 14 location)
5. Update "_layouts" folder with "_layouts/15" reference.
6. Update "CONTROLTEMPLATES" with "CONTROLTEMPLATES/15"
7. Build your solution, deploy and Test.

After successful deployment we are not able to add the web part to the page.We are getting an error like the following.

The file '/_controltemplates/15/{Project folder}/{web part Folder}/{Web PartUserControl}' does not exist.

Any one can help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it was related to wrong deployment under "\14" folder, that it's the old layout for Sharepoint 2010 compatibility mode.

I suggest you to deploy and check if your project is correctly comparing under these folders:

```
[Common Files]\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\[Your Project]
[Common Files]\\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\[Your Project]
[Common Files]\\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\[Your Project]
```

If you see that they are under \14 you need to find why.

In my case it was the Package.Package wrongly on "14.0"